# How to scrape ID using Python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I would like to scrape the div class = size along with 'ID' value using BeautifulSoup in Python.

```
<div class="size ">
 <a class="selectVar" id="23333" data="40593232" data-price="13000,00 €" data-tprice="" data-sh="107-42" data-size-original="92" data-eu="92" data-size-uk="5" data-size-us="5.5" data-size-cm="26.5" data-branch-2="1" data-branch-3="1" data-branch-4="1" data-branch-5="1" data-branch-6="1" data-branch-on="1">
  92
 </a>
</div>
```

I Have tried the following with no success:

```
product = soup.find("div", {'class': 'size ', 'type':'id'})['value']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track. 
To get the attributes of a tag, use the `tag.attrs` method:

```
# Find the <div> tag 
product_div = soup.find('div', {'class': 'size '})

# Find the <a> tag within the div
product_tag = product_div.find('a')

# Get the 'id' attribute of the <a> tag
product_id = product_tag.attrs['id']

print(product_id) # 23333
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfect. If there is multiple 'size ' in the HTML how can I print all, I used soup.find_all however I get AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find'

Comment: You'll need to loop through the tags returned by `soup.find_all`, e.g. `for product_div in soup.find('div', {'class': 'size '}):`