# How to scrape nontext in html?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get unique information from each container in a loop. I am using python 3.7 and BeautifulSoup to scrape.

I am running into an issue, where I am trying to get the unique player id number.

Here is the a tag that the number is nested in:

```
<a cache="true" class="flexpop" content="tabs#ppc" fpopheight="357px" fpopwidth="490px" href="" instance="_ppc" leagueid="216415" playerid="14880" seasonid="2018" tab="null" teamid="-2147483648"> /a>
```

I have tried a.split() to turn the a tag into a list, where I could just indice the data I want, but that doesnt work.

I tried to use the select function; a.select("playerid") but  get empty brackets like this [].

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: what language / library / framework are you using?

Comment: ay ,yes that would be useful info. I edited the question.

Comment: I think this SO answer cover your situation as well. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49148130/10864482

Comment: Awesome! It did. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could have used the following syntax as well

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
h = '<a cache="true" class="flexpop" content="tabs#ppc" fpopheight="357px" fpopwidth="490px" href="" instance="_ppc" leagueid="216415" playerid="14880" seasonid="2018" tab="null" teamid="-2147483648"> /a>'
soup = bs(h,'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('a[playerid]')['playerid'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for User23332, for pointing me in the direction to find the answer.

I just needed to do:

```
a.attrs['playerid']
```